# Resume design pattern for java

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm implementing a task, in which I need to perform 5-6 steps, and if my code fails at some step in between my requirement is to retry from the same step where it failed (This info I'm maintaining in a DB table), I can solve this thing with complex if-else check, but I'm looking for some standard or good way to solve this problem.

Comment: **Wizards**? My fellows might have totally other ideas here.

Comment: Do you need to implement it yourself or are you allowed to use external libraries?

Comment: I need to implement it myself.

Comment: The simplest way to accomplish this would be with `try/catch` blocks that called the same function again. You should have code outside of this block that controls how many retries have been done and stops execution after a determined number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep a list of subtasks and an index to specify where the execution stoped. Pseudocode:

```
public class Task {
    List<SubTask> subtasks;
    int executionIndex = 0;

    // ctor, getters, setters, etc...

    public void execute() {
         for (int i = executionIndex; i < subtasks.size(); ++i) {
             subtasks.get(i).execute();
             saveProgressToDB(i);
             ++exectionIndex;
         }
    }
}
```